# Model methods take document or query of type any

Tags: typegoose

After getting model for class using:

```js
const myModel = new Class().getModelForClass(Class)
```

I want to find one and delete using:

```js
await myModel.findOneAndDelete({...})
```

The problem I noticed is that the argument for `.findOneAndDelete()` has *any* type.

Is that default behavior of typegoose? Or is there something I'm missing?
I noticed same thing for saving etc.

Answer (score 0):

because typegoose dosnt modify any mongoose behavior, it is "any"

but you can use `{} as FilterQuery<Class>` (`FilterQuery` from `@types/mongodb`) or just simply `{} as Partial<Class>`

here an [github issue](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/129) explaining a bit more on why typegoose does this & a slightly different example